# Merging module from multiple files

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to merge declarations of a module split over multiple files? I.e. I would like to do something like this:

in file `Foo.ts`

```
import {Foo} from "./Foo1";
import {Foo} from "./Foo2";

export module Foo {
    export const foo = "Foo!";
}
```

in file `Foo1.ts`

```
export module Foo {
   export const foo1 = "Foo 1!";
}
```

in file `Foo2.ts`

```
export module Foo {
   export const foo2 = "Foo 2!";
}
```

in file `Bar.ts`

```
import {Foo} from "./Foo";

//access Foo.foo, Foo.foo1, Foo.foo2
```

However, the compiler complains about

```
import {Foo} from "./Foo1";
import {Foo} from "./Foo2";
```

Comment: Don't use `export module ...`. it's officially not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

create file `Foo.ts`:

```
export * from './Foo1';
export * from './Foo2';
```

also avoid `export module ...`. Just export the variables/functions you want as is.

Foo1:

```
export const foo1 = "Foo 1!";
```

Foo2:

```
export const foo2 = "Foo 2!";
```

and now in `Bar.ts` you can

```
import { foo1, foo2 } from './Foo';
```

or even:

```
import * as Foo from './Foo';
```